# I am trying to get data over an OpenWeather API in Rust but I am facing some iusse regarding parsing I guess

Tags: api, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates, rustup

```
extern crate openweather;
use openweather::LocationSpecifier;
static API_KEY: &str = "e85e0a3142231dab28a2611888e48f22";

fn main() {
    let loc = LocationSpecifier::Coordinates {
        lat: 24.87,
        lon: 67.03,
    };
    let weather = openweather::get_current_weather(loc, API_KEY).unwrap();

    print!(
        "Right now in Minneapolis, MN it is {}K",
        weather.main.humidity
    );
}
```

> error : thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an
>   `Err` value: ErrorReport { cod: 0, message: "Got unexpected response:
>   \"{\\"coord\\":{\\"lon\\":67.03,\\"lat\\":24.87},\\"weather\\":[{\\"id\\":803,\\"main\\":\\"Clouds\\",\\"description\\":\\"broken
>   clouds\\",\\"icon\\":\\"04n\\"}],\\"base\\":\\"stations\\",\\"main\\":{\\"temp\\":294.15,\\"pressure\\":1018,\\"humidity\\":60,\\"temp_min\\":294.15,\\"temp_max\\":294.15},\\"visibility\\":6000,\\"wind\\":{\\"speed\\":5.1,\\"deg\\":30},\\"clouds\\":{\\"all\\":70},\\"dt\\":1574012543,\\"sys\\":{\\"type\\":1,\\"id\\":7576,\\"country\\":\\"PK\\",\\"sunrise\\":1573955364,\\"sunset\\":1573994659},\\"timezone\\":18000,\\"id\\":1174872,\\"name\\":\\"Karachi\\",\\"cod\\":200}\""
>   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a JSON parsing error due to the deserialized struct not matching OpenWeather's JSON, perhaps the API recently added this? With your example, the [OpenWeatherCurrent](https://github.com/BroderickCarlin/openweather/blob/master/src/weather_types.rs#L122-L136) struct is missing `timezone`.

But it looks like there is an [open PR](https://github.com/BroderickCarlin/openweather/pull/7) that will fix this, you can test it by doing the following:

- Change your `Cargo.toml` dependency to `openweather = { git = "https://github.com/caemor/openweather" }`.
- The PR author has also updated the `get_current_weather` signature so you'll need to change lines 2, 10 to the following:

  ```rust
  use openweather::{LocationSpecifier, Settings};

  let weather = openweather::get_current_weather(&loc, API_KEY, &Settings::default()).unwrap();
  ```